# Best way to convert a vb6 "Type" (struct) to c#

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

I'm working on converting VB6 Code to C#. I'm struggling with converting the following VB6 Type to C#

```vb
Public Type XY_DATA
    InData(0 To 3) As Single
    PrevData(0 To 3) As Single
    OutData(0 To 3) As Single
    ZeroData(0 To 3) As Single
    StatXY(0 To 3) As Single
    DynXY(0 To 3) As Single
    UnbXY(0 To 3) As Single
    StdDev(0 To 3) As Single
End Type
```

Comment: Fortunately your lower array bound is zero which is the same as arrays in C#. This will make usage of this structure similar without introducing the chance of off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Visual Basic Update Wizard, which is bundled with Visual Studio 2008, to convert the VB code to VB.Net. Afterwards, convert the VB.Net (which is similar to C#) to C#.

In addition, Redgate Reflector can convert .Net assemblies to the language of your choice, with varying degrees of success. Thus, if you convert VB code to VB.Net and compile it, you may be able to generate equivalent C# code automatically.

Here's your code migrated and ported.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

public struct XY_DATA
{
    [VBFixedArray(3)]
    public Single[] InData;
    [VBFixedArray(3)]
    public Single[] PrevData;
    [VBFixedArray(3)]
    public Single[] OutData;
    [VBFixedArray(3)]
    public Single[] ZeroData;
    [VBFixedArray(3)]
    public Single[] StatXY;
    [VBFixedArray(3)]
    public Single[] DynXY;
    [VBFixedArray(3)]
    public Single[] UnbXY;
    [VBFixedArray(3)]
    public Single[] StdDev;

    // Note: "Initialize" must be called to initialize instances of this structure. 
    public void Initialize()
    {
        InData = new Single[4];
        PrevData = new Single[4];
        OutData = new Single[4];
        ZeroData = new Single[4];
        StatXY = new Single[4];
        DynXY = new Single[4];
        UnbXY = new Single[4];
        StdDev = new Single[4];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the attributes such as `VBFixedArray` are needed only if certain functions like `FileSystem.FilePut` will be used on the struct. Otherwise I believe they are superfluous (though harmless)

Comment: It could also be valid to create the equivalent of the VB6 Type as a C# class, not necessarily a struct. It depends on what it will be used for. Creating classes was inconvenient in VB6 so in some cases people used Types instead. Also, older versions of VB (< 6) did not have classes at all AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, a class is a better choice, but in this case the original was a value type and the example (generated by the VBUW) shows that type ported to C#.